# how to make a map<CLSID, string>?

Tags: stl, dictionary

I want to create a container which can associate a CLSID structure to something else (for example, a string); for example, std::map.

(the CLSID means standard Windows CLSID structure)

However when I want to use its find() and insert (object[clsid] = string), the STL just failed and gives errors.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

For example:

```
typedef std::map<CLSID, std::string> MyCLSIDMap;
MyCLSIDMap mymap;
CLSID sample = CLSID_NULL;

mymap[sample] = string("test");   // compilation failed here
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more info. Try pasting in some code (especially the code where you declare the map) and possibly the error messages. Then perhaps we can help.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Come on guys, at least try to compile it yourself :).

Answer (score 5):

As Alex has answered, std::map needs to compare it's keys with op<.

```
bool operator<(CLSID const& l, CLSID const& r)
{
    return memcmp(&l, &r, sizeof(CLSID)) < 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your CLSID structure support a usable operator<()?  That's crucial for std::map (you can build it as a separate bool functor taking two const CLSID& arguments, it doesn't have to be a method operator<() in CLSID -- but then you'll have to say std::map and not just map ...!).

Answer (score 0):

To use an STL map where the keys are structures, you'll need to provide your own strict weak ordering function object:

```
struct CompareCLSID
{
  bool operator()(const CLSID &s1, const CLSID &s2) const
  {
    // returns true if s1 is less than s2
  }
};
```

and then your map's type would be map<CLSID, string, CompareCLSID>.

However, if you don't need your container is sorted (that's my guess), you should be using hash<> or hash_map<>. In that case, you'll have to provide your own hash function.

Comment: Just defining an operator< is enough in this case. Defining a simple function (bool CompareCLSID(...) {} is the same thing if you have no state) or function object is useful if you need to switch out the behavior.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a simple function to map. Can you give an example?

defining operator<() will work, but I'd recommend against defining it in a public interface, if it's ad-hoc for the map and there isn't a lot of meaning in comparing those objects.

Comment: This will look dumb in a comment: "
typedef std::map<CLSID, std::string, bool(*)(CLSID const&,CLSID const&)> map_t;
map_t map(&cmpCLSID);"